# ThisWorkbook UsedRange error – Variable not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I have code copied from the internet and modified to loop through a column of values in a worksheet to write to separate files to split up the data.

I have it working in one worksheet.

In the second worksheet, with UsedRange, I get

> Compile error, variable not defined

This code works.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitCaseData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim p As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each p In Sheets("Location").Range("LocList")
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        
        WriteLocationToWorkbook wb, p.Value
        
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\casedata_" & p.Value
        wb.Close
    Next p
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub

Sub WriteLocationToWorkbook(ByVal CaseWB As Workbook, _
                            ByVal Location As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim caseRows As Range     'Stores all of the rows found
                                'containing Location in column 1
    For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows
        If Location = rw.Cells(1, 1) Then
            If caseRows Is Nothing Then
                Set caseRows = rw
            Else
                Set caseRows = Union(caseRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    
    caseRows.Copy CaseWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    Set caseRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code doesn't work.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim p As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each p In Sheets("Location").Range("sitesplit")
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        
        WriteLocToWorkbook wb, p.Value
        
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\testsplit_" & p.Value
        wb.Close
    Next p
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub

Sub WriteLocToWorkbook(ByVal LocWB As Workbook, _
                       ByVal Location As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim LocationRows As Range     'Stores all of the rows found
                                'containing Location in column 1
    For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows
        If Location = rw.Cells(1, 1) Then
            If LocationRows Is Nothing Then
                Set LocationRows = rw
            Else
                Set LocationRows = Union(LocationRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    
    LocationRows.Copy LocWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    Set LocationRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

Apart from different variable names, I can't see what I've done differently between the two.

Comment: Where's the error in the second block?

Comment: `UsedRange` is the property of a worksheet. You need to specify the sheet.

Comment: Hi, @Tim Williams, thanks for replying, the error is with UsedRange - it says it isn't defined

Comment: Hi BigBen, I thought I had defined it to be the ActiveWorksheet.  I can't see any difference in my declarations between the first and second pieces of code?

Comment: I don't see how the first block runs without also erroring on `UsedRange`

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` where you plan to use `UsedRange`? Is it worksheet `Location` or some other worksheet?

Comment: It is Location - location has the list of location_ids which are used to split the file into separate files

Answer (score 0):

### Copy by Criteria Using Loop

**A Quick Fix (not tested)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TESTsplitData()
    splitData "LocList", "casedata"
    splitData "sitesplit", "testsplit"
End Sub

Sub splitData( _
        ByVal RangeName As String, _
        ByVal FolderPart As String)
    
    Const srcName As String = "Location"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim cel As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each cel In src.Range(RangeName).Cells
        With Workbooks.Add
            writeLocationToWorkbook src, .Worksheets(1), cel.Value
            .SaveAs wb.Path & "\" & FolderPart & "_" & cel.Value
            .Close
        End With
    Next cel
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub writeLocationToWorkbook( _
        src As Worksheet, _
        dst As Worksheet, _
        ByVal Location As String)
    
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Dim caseRows As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    
    For Each rw In src.UsedRange.Rows
        If rw.Range(srcFirst).Value = Location Then
            If caseRows Is Nothing Then
                Set caseRows = rw
            Else
                Set caseRows = Union(caseRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    
    If Not caseRows Is Nothing Then
        caseRows.Copy dst.Range(dstFirst)
    End If

End Sub
```